# High chemical resistance, high thermal conductivity?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, thermodynamics

I'm redesigning a microfluidic circuit to include a heating element. I'm running into problems because the ETFE tubing I'm using is too thermally resistant for me to get any energy into the fluid within. My options are to either 1) replace the ETFE tubing with a polymer with similar chemical and surface properties but a higher thermal conductivity, or 2) replace just the beginning of the circuit tubing with a similarly chemically resistant, but possibly rigid, material that can transfer a lot of heat to the fluid, which would then be insulated by the ETFE on its way to its destination.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

[Edit]: Also, affordability is a slight factor. This question is industrial in nature so a certain operating budget can be assumed - but exotics are going to be hard to get.

I like the diamond comment though; I wish I could pull that off.

Comment: Well, diamond comes to mind, but that might not be so easy...

Comment: What does it need to be chemically resistant to?

Comment: Post-edit: diamond-like coatings are not hard to get commercially, and retain some of the inertness. Also it depends on the temperature and what you want resistance to.

Comment: You may use borides